# Filtering values out of a bson.M in golang

Tags: mongodb, dictionary, go, bson, mgo

I am quite new to golang and wanted to filter name and version for packages out of a response from my mongodb. I am using mgo to get the respone from the mongodb.
This is my Code to get the response from my mongodb:

```
    pipe := c.Pipe([]bson.M{{"$match": bson.M{"host": "test.server.lan"}}})
    resp := []bson.M{}

    err := pipe.All(&resp)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("oh")
    }
    fmt.Println(resp)
```

The output of the response:

```
[map[_id:ObjectIdHex("4de39d42ke9fc601db635618") host:test.server.lan installed:[map[arch:all homepage: name:adduser status:ii vendor: version:3.118] map[arch:all homepage: name:adwaita-icon-theme status:ii vendor: version:3.30.1-1] map[arch:all homepage: name:ampua-watchdog status:ii vendor: version:2.2.2~ui10] map[arch:amd64 homepage:http://apparmor.net/ name:apparmor status:ii vendor: version:2.13.2-10] map[arch:amd64 homepage: name:apt status:ii vendor: version:1.8.2] map[arch:all homepage: name:apt-listchanges status:ii vendor: version:3.19] map[arch:amd64 homepage: name:apt-utils status:ii vendor: version:1.8.2] map[arch:amd64 homepage: name:base-files status:ii vendor: version:10.3+deb10u2]
```

I just want the the name and the version for each package.

Comment: By default, queries in MongoDB return all fields in matching documents. To limit the amount of data that MongoDB sends to applications, you can include a projection document to specify or restrict fields to return.

Answer (score 0):

The response you receive is an object which has an internal `String() string` method and is thus outputted this way.

It is composed out out slices and maps and looks formatted like this:

```
[
    map[
        _id:ObjectIdHex("4de39d42ke9fc601db635618")
        host:test.server.lan
        installed:
        [
            map[
                arch:all
                homepage:
                name:adduser
                status:ii
                vendor:
                version:3.118
            ]
            map[
                arch:all
                homepage:
                name:adwaita-icon-theme
                status:ii
                vendor:
                version:3.30.1-1
            ]
            map[
                arch:all
                homepage:
                name:ampua-watchdog
                status:ii
                vendor:
                version:2.2.2~ui10
            ]
            ...
```

A maybe more familiar appearance would be:

```
[
    {
        "_id":ObjectIdHex("4de39d42ke9fc601db635618"),
        "host":"test.server.lan",
        "installed":
        [
            {
                "arch":"all",
                "homepage":"",
                "name":"adduser",
                "status":"ii",
                "vendor":"",
                "version":"3.118"
            },
            {
                "arch":"all",
                "homepage":"",
                "name":"adwaita-icon-theme",
                "status":"ii",
                "vendor":"",
                "version":"3.30.1-1"
            },
            {
                "arch":"all",
                "homepage":"",
                "name":"ampua-watchdog",
                "status":"ii",
                "vendor":"",
                "version":"2.2.2~ui10"
            },
            ...
```

But is basically the same.
To iterate over the resp you can do:

```golang
for server := range resp {
    fmt.Printf("Host: %s\n", server.host)
    for installedPackage := range server.installed {
        fmt.Printf("\tPackage: %s\tVersion: %s\n", installedPackage.name, installedPackage.version)
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried the above code, and I am getting `server.host undefined (type string has no field or method subject)` in VS Code.

Comment: Sounds like you have different data. Where your `server` already appears to be a string.

Comment: Yes, only names are different. VS Code is not translating `server` as an object. I have implemented the `Struct` strategy which makes more sense to me and easy for other to understand. You can have a look to my post.

Answer (score 0):

In order to display only selected fields, use $project.

Refer: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/

```
pipe :=c.Pipe([]bson.M{
        {
            "$match": bson.M{
               "host":"test.server.lan"
             },
        },

        {
            "$project": bson.M{
                "version": 1,
                "name":  1,
            },
        },
      })
```

Answer (score 0):

Better approach would be to use Struct with the values you need and use find method to fetch the record from database and map your struct to populate it with values.

### Struct

```golang
type DisplayQuestion struct {
    ID              primitive.ObjectID  `json:"id,omitempty" bson:"_id,,omitempty"`
    Question        string `json:"question,omitempty" bson:"question,omitempty"`
}
```

### Sample Code

Point to note is, the collection has more fields but here we are mapping only 2 fields(ID and Question) which we have defiend in Struct.

```golang
func GetQuestionByID(ctx context.Context, docID string) (error) {

 mydatabase := db.Conn.Database("my_database")
 myCollection := database.Collection("my_collection")
 myID, err := primitive.ObjectIDFromHex(docID)
    
 var questionStruct DisplayQuestion
 err = myCollection.FindOne(ctx, bson.M{"_id": questionID}).Decode(&questionStruct)
 fmt.Printf("Here is the question   : %s\t\n", questionStruct.Qution)

}
```